# How do I add shading and color to the confidence intervals in ggplot 2 generated Kaplan-Meier plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, ggally

I would like to have the shading of the confidence intervals for the survival estimates. Now I have black lines.

```
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
data(lung) 
sf.sex <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung) 
pl.sex <- ggsurv(sf.sex, CI = TRUE) 
pl.sex
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better solution. You just use the Rcmdrplugin KMggplot2 which also has the optional features of adding the median line and number at risk table.

[image]

Comment: This answer would be improved if you provide the code for the plot.

Comment: @FTF : This answer could be markedly improve if you provide the codes as I tried it but it gives me several errors!

Answer (score 9):

Here is an easy, almost-right solution:

```
pl.sex <- ggsurv(sf.sex, CI = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low,ymax=up,fill=group),alpha=0.3)
```

Set `CI = FALSE` to get rid of the dashed-line CI bands then add `geom_ribbon()` to get the confidence bands you want.

[image]

This is only mostly right, though, since we want the confidence bands to use the step function as well.  To get exactly what we want, we can use some code from [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/9cFWHaH1CPs) to create a new `stat` for geom_ribbon called "stepribbon" as follows:

```
library(proto)

stairstepn <- function( data, direction="hv", yvars="y" ) {
  direction <- match.arg( direction, c( "hv", "vh" ) )
  data <- as.data.frame( data )[ order( data$x ), ]
  n <- nrow( data )

  if ( direction == "vh" ) {
    xs <- rep( 1:n, each = 2 )[ -2 * n ]
    ys <- c( 1, rep( 2:n, each = 2 ) )
  } else {
    ys <- rep( 1:n, each = 2 )[ -2 * n ]
    xs <- c( 1, rep( 2:n, each = 2))
  }

  data.frame(
    x = data$x[ xs ]
    , data[ ys, yvars, drop=FALSE ]
    , data[ xs, setdiff( names( data ), c( "x", yvars ) ), drop=FALSE ]
  )
}

stat_stepribbon <- function( mapping=NULL, data=NULL, geom="ribbon", position="identity" ) {
  StatStepribbon$new( mapping=mapping, data=data, geom=geom, position=position )
}

StatStepribbon <- proto(ggplot2:::Stat, {
  objname <- "stepribbon"
  desc <- "Stepwise area plot"
  desc_outputs <- list(
    x = "stepped independent variable",
    ymin = "stepped minimum dependent variable",
    ymax = "stepped maximum dependent variable"
  )
  required_aes <- c( "x", "ymin", "ymax" )

  default_geom <- function(.) GeomRibbon
  default_aes <- function(.) aes( x=..x.., ymin = ..y.., ymax=Inf )

  calculate <- function( ., data, scales, direction = "hv", yvars = c( "ymin", "ymax" ), ...) {
    stairstepn( data = data, direction = direction, yvars = yvars )
  }

  examples <- function(.) {
    DF <- data.frame( x = 1:3, ymin = runif( 3 ), ymax=rep( Inf, 3 ) )
    ggplot( DF, aes( x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax ) ) + stat_stepribbon()
  }

})
```

With that new `stat` you can get the solution I think you were really looking for:

```
pl.sex <- ggsurv(sf.sex, CI = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low,ymax=up,fill=group),stat="stepribbon",alpha=0.3) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend("sex"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SamDickson, but now there are two legends -- one for the line and one for the ribbon. How can I correct that?

Comment: Combining the legends is as simple as making sure they have the same name.  The answer has been updated to show you one way to do this. A slightly shorter is to use `+labs(fill="sex")`.