# Add shaded confidence interval to ggflexsurv plot

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, survminer

ggflexsurv from the package survminer seems to only support dashed confidence interval lines rather than shaded/filled. I've tried a few work arounds, such as this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874909/how-do-i-add-shading-and-color-to-the-confidence-intervals-in-ggplot-2-generated) but to no avail.

My last attempt was to inset the code from the answer in the linked thread into the source code for ggflexsurv

```r
ggflexsurvplotmod <- function(fit, 
                               data = NULL,
                               fun = c("survival", "cumhaz"),
                               summary.flexsurv = NULL,
                               size = 1, 
                               conf.int = FALSE,
                               conf.int.flex = conf.int, 
                               conf.int.km = FALSE,
                               legend.labs = NULL,...)
  
{
  
  if (!requireNamespace("flexsurv", quietly = TRUE)){
    stop("flexsurv package needed for this function to work. Please install it.")}
  
  if(!inherits(fit, "flexsurvreg")){
    stop("Can't handle an object of class ", class(fit))
    fun <- match.arg(fun)}
  
  data <- .get_data(fit, data = data, complain = FALSE)
  
  summ <- .summary_flexsurv(fit, type = fun,
                            summary.flexsurv = summary.flexsurv)
  
  .strata <- summ$strata
  
  n.strata <- .strata %>% .levels() %>% length()
  
  fit.ext <- .extract.survfit(fit)
  
  surv.obj <- fit.ext$surv
  
  surv.vars <- fit.ext$variables
  
  .formula <- fit.ext$formula
  
  isfac <- .is_all_covariate_factor(fit)
  
  if(!all(isfac))
  {.formula <- .build_formula(surv.obj, "1")
    n.strata <- 1}
  
  if(n.strata == 1 & missing(conf.int)) conf.int <- TRUE
  
  # Fit KM survival curves
  
  #::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
x <- do.call(survival::survfit, 
             list(formula = .formula, data = data))

fun <- if(fun == "survival") NULL else fun

ggsurv <- ggsurvplot_core(x, 
                          data = data, 
                          size = 0.5,
                          fun = fun, 
                          conf.int = conf.int.km,
                          legend.labs = legend.labs, ...)
  
  # Overlay the fitted models
  
  #::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  
  # Check legend labels if specified
  
  if(!is.null(legend.labs)){
    
    if(n.strata != length(legend.labs))
      stop("The length of legend.labs should be ", n.strata )
    
    summ$strata <- factor(summ$strata,
                          levels = .levels(.strata),
                          labels = legend.labs)
    
  }
  
  time <- est <- strata <- lcl <- ucl <- NULL

ggsurv$plot <- 
    ggsurv$plot +
    geom_line(aes(time, 
                  est, 
                  color = strata),
              data = summ, 
              size = size)
  
  #CODE FROM PREVIOUS STACKOVERFLOW THREAD#######
  
  stairstepn <- function( data, direction="hv", yvars="y" )
    {direction <- match.arg(direction, c("hv", "vh") )
    data <- as.data.frame(data)[ order( data$x ), ]
    n <- nrow( data )
  
  if ( direction == "vh" ) {
    xs <- rep( 1:n, each = 2 )[ -2 * n ]
    ys <- c( 1, rep( 2:n, each = 2 ) )
  } else {
    ys <- rep( 1:n, each = 2 )[ -2 * n ]
    xs <- c( 1, rep( 2:n, each = 2))
  }
  
  data.frame(
    x = data$x[ xs ]
    , data[ ys, yvars, drop=FALSE ]
    , data[ xs, setdiff( names( data ), c( "x", yvars ) ), drop=FALSE ]
  ) 
  
  }
  
  stat_stepribbon <- function(mapping = NULL, 
                              data = NULL, 
                              geom = "ribbon", 
                              position = "identity", 
                              inherit.aes = TRUE) 
  {ggplot2::layer(stat = Stepribbon, 
                    mapping = mapping, 
                  data = data, 
                  geom = geom,
                  position = position, 
                  inherit.aes = inherit.aes)}
  
  StatStepribbon <- ggproto("stepribbon", 
                            Stat,
                            compute_group = 
                              function(., data, scales, 
                                       direction = "hv",
                                       yvars = c( "ymin", "ymax" ), ...)
                                {stairstepn(data = data,
                                            direction = direction,
                                            yvars = yvars )},
                            required_aes = c( "x", "ymin", "ymax" ))
  
  ###########################################################################
  
  if(conf.int.flex) ggsurv$plot <- ggsurv$plot+
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lcl,
                    ymax = ucl), 
                fill = strata, 
                stat = "stepribbon", 
                data = summ, 
                alpha=0.3)
  
  #other version of geom_ribbon() attempted
  #geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lcl,ymax=ucl), data = summ,fill=strata, alpha=0.3) #stat="identity"
  #original code in package
  #geom_line(aes(time, lcl, color = strata), data = summ, #size = 0.5, linetype = "dashed")+
  
  #geom_line(aes(time, ucl, color = strata), data = summ, #size = 0.5, linetype = "dashed")
  
  ggsurv
  
}

.summary_flexsurv <- function(fit, type = "survival", summary.flexsurv = NULL){
  
  summ <- summary.flexsurv
  
  if(is.null(summary.flexsurv)){
    summ <- summary(fit, type = type)}
  
  if(length(summ) == 1){summ <- summary(fit)[[1]] %>%
    dplyr::mutate(strata = "All")}
  
  else{.strata <- names(summ)
  summ <- purrr::pmap(list(.strata, summ), function(.s, .summ){
    dplyr::mutate(.summ, strata = .s )})
  summ <- dplyr::bind_rows(summ)
  summ$strata <- factor(summ$strata, levels = .strata)}
  
  summ
  
}

# Check if all covariates are factor or character vector

.is_all_covariate_factor <- function(fit){
  x <- fit
mf <- stats::model.frame(x)
Xraw <- mf[,attr(mf, "covnames.orig"), drop=FALSE]
dat <- x$datasapply(Xraw,is_factor_or_character)}

is_factor_or_character <- function(x){is.facet(x) | is.character(x)}

#This code "saves" the modified code into the packageenvironment(ggflexsurvplotmod) <- asNamespace('survminer')
assignInNamespace("ggflexsurvplot", ggflexsurvplotmod, ns = "survminer")
```

I then run the following

```
 code_example =  flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung,dist = "gompertz")

ggflexsurvplotmod(code_example, conf.int = T) `
```

which results in the following error

> Error in geom_ribbon():
> Problem while computing aesthetics.
> i Error occurred in the 5th layer.
> Caused by error:
> object 'surv' not found`

Comment: very likely, you are getting an error because the code is jumbled, in many places, newlines are missing, and in some places commentary text is not behind `#`.

Comment: That's a direct result of the formatting problems I've been having with Stackoverflow, I've had to go back and reformat several times already. I've just gone back through and had another go. Thank you for your suggestion in any case!

Comment: maybe you can fix the obvious formatting errors inside the code block? then this question would maybe appeal to other contributors and your chances of getting an answer would be increased.

Comment: I fixed everything within my post that I could find before I made my previous comment. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Ashley, I hand formatted the code to be able to run and edited your question. We have to wait that the edit is approved by a high ranked community member.

Comment: Thanks, Uke! I appreciate that you took the time to do so.